# Upload image in expo ImagePicker without aws amplify

Tags: react-native, aws-sdk, expo, react-native-image-picker

I am using aws-sdk can I upload images without using aws amplify I'm using expo's ImagePicker module to select the image how can I put selected image from local file path to s3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React native Fetch API should work with AWS Signed URL

You can upload any resources into your S3 without credentials or external libraries if you have signed url.